# anybody doing a class tree in Dart?

Tags: class, types, dart, dart-mirrors

`Dart`s `Mirrors` are for me currently poorly documented and very difficult to experiment with - they behave differently in code than from within the console.

for my own use, I would love to be able to treat classes (`Type`s) as a trees, with a node being something like:

```dart
class Node {
  type ...  <== Type itself
  name ...  <== name of current class
  super ... <== super of this class, eg, extends super
  mixins ... <== mixins used to build this Type
  extendChildren ... <== Types for which this type is super
  mixinChildren ... <== Types for which this type is a mixin
}
```

for the life of me, I cannot get something this basic out of current `Mirrors`.  hoping that somebody smarter than me has given it a shot!!

Answer (score 3):

Below is a simple example which prints the name of the superclass and the name of Foo's members.

Note that the API uses Symbols, not strings. These are required so that dart2js can minify code that uses mirrors, they're a bit of a pain, but they mean that your code will run cross browser, and be compact.

To convert between symbols and strings see [MirrorSystem.getName()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorSystem.html#getName) and [MirrorSystem.getSymbol()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorSystem.html#getSymbol) (Actually I believe you can just use new Symbol('foo') now).

Also note a new feature was recently added giving a special literal syntax for symbols. Up until recently you needed to type const Symbol('foo'), now just #foo, you may see a mix of old an new when looking at examples.

See this [article](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/reflection-with-mirrors/) for more information about mirrors.

Warning - probably a few typos in the example.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Bob {
}

class Foo extends Bob {
   String bar = 'jim';
}

main() {
  var classMirror = reflectClass(Foo);

  print(MirrorSystem.getName(classMirror.superClass.simpleName));

  classMirror.declarations.values.forEach((d) => print(MirrorSystem.getName(d.simpleName)));
}
```

Update: Based on what Alan said below (Also untested):

Example source:

```dart
library foo;

class B extends A {
}

class A {
}
```

Definition:

```dart
List<ClassMirror> findSubClasses(Symbol libraryName, ClassMirror superClass) =>
    currentMirrorSystem().findLibrary(libraryName).declarations.values
        .where((d) => d is ClassMirror 
            && d.superClass.simpleName == superClass.simpleName);
```

Usage:

```dart
var cm = reflectClass(A);
var subclasses = findSubClasses(#foo, cm);
```

There is a [@MirrorsUsed](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorsUsed.html) attribute that you may want to experiment with if you're interested on compiling to js. It's still experimental so expect this to change.

Comment: thanks.  was able to get this far.  where I was stumped was getting children - from `super/extend` and `mixin/with`.  any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean this? classMirror.superClass.declarations.values.forEach(....)  I haven't tried using mirrors with mixins. What does this print out?classMirror.mixin.declarations.values.forEach(...)

Comment: I dont' think you can get subclasses from the class itself, you'd need to iterate over all classes and ask for the superclass. And similarly for mixins. Annoying, but I think it has a tree-shaking rationale, that if, from any class you can get to subclasses, then from any class you can get anywhere so you have no way to know what's visible.

Comment: oops sub/super - gotcha.

Comment: @AlanKnight- is there even a mechanism for iterating over all classes?

Comment: Yes. currentMirrorSystem().findLibrary(#libraryName).declarations.values.where((d) => d is ClassMirror) Have a look at the update to my answer.